# UIWebView Expose Objective C to JavaScript

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

How would I expose an *Objective-C* method within JavaScript when using the *iPhone SDK* when using the `UIWebView`?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The best way to do this would be through a custom link, and then use the UIWebView delegate method `-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` to trap requests. When you see a request come through with your link in it, you know your action has been triggered.

Comment: I do not believe this will work, when I was testing something similar the resource policy delegates were only called in response to user initiated actions, script initiates actions were silently dropped. it is possible this has changed since I checked back in June.

Comment: I just tried a very simple page who's onload function set the page's location to www.google.com, and the request was passed to the delegate.

Answer (score 3):

There is an example application in the QuickConnectiPhone framework that shows you how to do this.

QuickConnectiPhone also gives you a JavaScript function called 'makeCall'.  You pass it a command and an array of parameters and it will pass them to the Objective-C side of your app for handling.  You can then make your function call.

You can find it [here on Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/quickconnect/).

Answer (score 0):

To see an example of this check out the PhoneGap source code from Github:

http://github.com/sintaxi/phonegap/tree/master/iphone/Classes/GlassAppDelegate.m

Comment: Link nolonger valid and needs updating